# Tuleap Project - Display the correct SSH Address in Git Clone Address Window When Using a Custom SSH Port in Docker

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, gitolite, tuleap

We are successfully running Tuleap Community Edition (CE) 13.7.99.124 in a docker container with an external database. We have modified our docker-compose.yml file to point the ssh port to 2222 so we can still remote into the virtual machine on port 22.

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    image: tuleap/tuleap-community-edition
    hostname: ${TULEAP_FQDN}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "2222:22"
    volumes:
      - tuleap-data:/data
[...]
```

We can successfully clone with git over ssh using port 2222. However, the clone address displayed in the Tuleap project is incorrect and is missing the port. The correct address of

`ssh://gitolite@our-domain.com:2222/myproject/agitrepo.git`

is  displayed as

`ssh://gitolite@our-domain.com/myproject/agitrepo.git`

And all interactions obviously fail.

How do I get Tuleap to display the correct git clone address for SSH when using a custom SSH port?